# Config spec for applying a label

Tags: clearcase

How to apply a label To the latest version of a branch Using config Spec?
Can we apply a label using the Config spec.

Well I have created branches using the Config spec but I applied labels using the apply label option.
But i want to apply it by giving it in the config spec.

Can we do it if so how?

I tried it but Its not working.Thank you in advance

```
element  *   CHECKEDOUT  
element  /test_ari/karthik/omna.txt  .../karthik_9/LATEST/karthik_66
element  *  /main/LATEST
```

I want to create a label `karthik_66` on `karthik_9/LATEST` using config spec rules but how do i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [config spec rules man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm), you can use labels within a config spec to *select* a version, not to label one.
So "no".

When you create/manage a branch, [you need 3 rules](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_config_rules_subbranch.htm), not 1 like yo currently have:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT

# 3 rules here:
element /test_ari/karthik/* .../karthik_9/LATEST
element /test_ari/karthik/* /main/LATEST -mkbranch karthik_9
element /main/0  .../karthik_9/LATEST

element * /main/LATEST
```

That would create a branch for any file (not just `omna.txt`) inside /test_ari/karthik, as well for any new file (the `/main/0` selection rule).

Since you view would always refers to `.../karthik_9/LATEST`, you can then apply your label at any time, setting it on the `LATEST` of `karthik_9`.

Comment: how do i apply it VOn you did not tell me the Config spec for applying a label you said for a branch

Comment: how to apply a label karthik_66 for karthik_9/LATEST branch using the config spec technique?

Comment: @niko: I was editing my answer: it doesn't seem possible to label *directly* from a config spec. Feel free to discuss it at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1204/clearcase

Comment: so you cannot apply a label using the config spec?

Comment: @niko: yes, a config spec will be used to select versions or make new branches, but not for applying labels (except the special shifting one which is `LATEST`)