# Integration stream vs integration view in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

In clear case terminology, what is the difference between integration stream and integration view? Development stream and development view?

More specifically, why "[joining an UCM project](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_join_ucm_proj.htm)" involves creating *both* integration and development views?

[image: join UCM project dialog]

If I am a developer, not an integrator, should only *one* view be enough?

Comment: @VonC See, that's *much* better, as it shows something *much* more concrete (and we have to make these judgement calls across all the technologies represented on SO) which makes it an easier call to reopen.

Comment: @casperOne: no problem. I am so used to that question in my training sessions I give regularly on UCM that I didn't take the time to "translate" Kaushik's question into a more complete version. Thank you for reminding me of my duties here on SO ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Integration is a term used by convention to designate the first root stream of an UCM project.
Each UCM project has one root stream (and potentially many sub-streams).
The idea is that you will use your integration view as the destination view for deliver coming from sub-streams, effectively "integrated" the work done on said sub-streams on that integration view.

[image: Integration Stream]
<sup>(Froml [Stream hierarchy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pln_strm_int_confg.htm))</sup>

Any sub-stream is called by convention a "development" Stream, in that it represents the "configuration" (ie what you need to work) for your current "**[development effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567135/clearcase-issue/1567308#1567308)**".

A Stream is a configuration.
An UCM view is a ClearCase view with a config spec done automatically for you following the configuration of the Stream (instead of [writing those selection rules manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648945/6309)).

The integration view is a view with the Integration Stream as reference.
A Development view is a view with a development Stream as reference.

The main idea behind this **[hierarchy of streams](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pln_strm_hrrch_tgt.htm)** is to visualize your [merge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212/how-do-you-maintain-development-code-and-production-code#216228) (ie: once you have finished a work on a branch '`B`', where do you need to merge said work?)

[image: merge workflow]

- merge from a sub-stream to a parent stream: **deliver**
- merge from a parent stream to an immediate child stream: **rebase**