# CCRC: Synchronize view with stream from command-line

Tags: clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

The config spec of a CCRC view can be synchronized with the stream from CCRC eclipse UI by calling 'Refresh->Update from repository'.

I wanted to know if there is a way to do it from command-line. I have tried 'rcleartool update' command. But I don't think it actually updates the config spec of the view from the stream. I might be wrong ??

Has anyone tried this using CM API? Or any other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

com.ibm.rational.wvcm.stp.cc.CcView.doRefresh() method solves this problem.

More documentation on how to get a CcView object and javadoc should be available in your CCRC installation - C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\common\CM\teamapi.zip.

Unzip and see - projects\samples\doc\index.html for sample programs.

--- More details..Sample code ---

```
StpProvider provider = (StpProvider) ProviderFactory.createProvider(
                    CcProvider.CC_ONLY_PROVIDER_CLASS,
                    new DefaultCallback());
provider.setServerUrl(<CM SERVER URL>);
m_provider = provider.ccProvider();

File viewRoot = new File(<PATH TO VIEW ROOT>);
StpLocation viewLocation = provider.filePathLocation(StpProvider.Domain.CLEAR_CASE, viewRoot);

// Get instance of CcView that represents the CCRC view.
CcView view = provider.ccView(viewLocation);

// Options while updating view
CcFile.RefreshFlag[] refreshFlags = new CcFile.RefreshFlag[1];
refreshFlags[0] = CcFile.RefreshFlag.OVERWRITE_HIJACKS;

PropertyRequestItem.PropertyRequest properties = new PropertyRequestItem.PropertyRequest(CcView.DISPLAY_NAME, CcView.CONFIG_SPEC);

view.doRefresh(refreshFlags, properties);
```

Comment: Interesting feedback (+1) ,  but could you detail a bit more?

Comment: @VonC : Updated my post with sample code. Hope it helps. The JavaDoc and sample program in installation should help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that feature available when looking at the [list of rcleartool commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929).

The *`cleartool`* (not `rcleartool`) command behind a "synchronize with stream" is

```
cleartool setcs -stream
```

(See "[Synchronize with stream clear case integration view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948832/synchronize-with-stream-clear-case-integration-view/9949209#9949209)" for more)

And `setcs` isn't part of the rcleartool commands.

Comment: We were using clearcase with UCM and it was pretty easy to do it with setcs command. But as you point out, there isn't a easy to replace command to do this in CCRC. Back to exploring options with CM API.

Comment: @Veera: if you find a "cm api"-based solution, let us know by posting an answer here.