# Clearcase: Does rebasing a stream in your snapshot view affect other users views on that stream

Tags: clearcase

Does rebasing a stream in your snapshot view affect other users of that stream. For example, say I change to my view of stream_x, then do a

```
ct rebase -reco
ct rebase -complete
```

Does the rebase affect the stream_x or only my view of that stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: if you have one stream per developers (following a [development stream/view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880031/integration-stream-vs-integration-view-in-clearcase/9880266#9880266)), all children of a common stream (on which a baseline has been recommended), then rebasing your view with said recommended baseline won't affect any other developer's view.
It will affect (as I describe below) the views associated with that Stream, ie in this case your views (you can have more than one associated with your Stream).

---

Original answer:

Yes it will, but not immediately.
The configuration (list of baselines) of the Stream will have changed.
All the associated UCM view are basing their config spec on that list.
However, they want update their config spec automatically.

- Other users with a snapshot view will see at their next update a dialog box proposing to synchronize their view view their Stream.
- Other users with dynamic view won't see the change right away, but their view property will display a button "Synchronize with Stream"

[image: dynamic view synchronize with stream]

See "[Synchronize with stream clear case integration view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948832/synchronize-with-stream-clear-case-integration-view/9949209#9949209)" for more.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that a rebase is needed because the baseline for stream_x changed. I did not think that rebase on my_view_stream_x would change the baseline for stream_x.

Comment: Also what happens if 2 people rebase a stream at the same time? For example, person 1 changes to his view of a stream then person 2 changes to their view, they both rebase -reco, rebase -complete. If that affects the stream for everyone that means all users will get multiple notifications.

Comment: @sashang: rebasing on your view will change the stream, yes. More specifically, it will change the baseline by the one produced and recommended on the *parent* stream. Now if your Stream is a development stream dedicated to you, that is if no other views are based on that Stream, then you won't have any issue.

Comment: @sashang what happens if 2 people rebase a stream at the same time? The last update prevails, and override any change introduced by the first update.

Comment: @sashang I have edited my answer to amend it with the "one stream per developer" model.