# clearcase: rebase -reco and changes to other peoples code

Tags: clearcase

If this is the workflow of Bob and Jane:

```
Bob:
ct setview bob_stream_x
ct rebase -reco

Jane:
ct setview jane_stream_x
<make a new build>
```

will the build Jane makes contain the changes from Bob's rebase of stream_x? Or does Bob have to do a 'ct rebase -complete'?

Answer (score 0):

Two things actually:

1. Bob has to complete the rebase, for it to be visible by other views
2. If `jane_stream_x` view is on the same stream than `bob_stream_x` view, then Jane would have to do first a '`cleartool setcs -stream -tag jane_stream_x`, before her view reflects the new configuration.

However, if `jane_stream_x` view is on a dedicate "`jane_stream_x`" Stream (different than `bob_stream_x`), then Jane would have to do the `cleartool rebase -reco`, `cleartool rebase -complete` as well, to see the same configuration than in `bob_stream_x` view.
The rebase made by Bob would have no consequence on Jane's Stream and Jane's view.

Considering your previous question "[Clearcase: Does rebasing a stream in your snapshot view affect other users views on that stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025850/clearcase-does-rebasing-a-stream-in-your-snapshot-view-affect-other-users-views)", that could very well be the case here (ie one stream per developer, which [I always found not a very satisfactory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567135/clearcase-issue/1567308#1567308) ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify the model/paradigm in use here is not one stream per developer. Streams are created according to what needs to be developed. For example if there is a bugfix needed for a stream, a child stream is created with a the name <parent_name>_<bug number> and then multiple developers can set views to this stream and work on it.

Comment: @sashang Ok. In that case (several views on the same Stream), points 1. and 2. apply to your situation.