# find last merge done to a branch clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have two integration branch `int_1` and `int_2`.
In the time there has always been merged from `int_1` to `int_2`.

I want to know when was the last time a merge was done on `int_2` branch from `int_1` branch.
Is there any command to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about UCM integration branches, that means you have done delivered from one [integration Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880031/integration-stream-vs-integration-view-in-clearcase/9880266#9880266) of one UCM project to another integration Stream of another project.

In that case, go to the destination branch `int_2`, and look for `deliver.xxx` activities. The most recent one will tell you when the last deliver was done.

With base ClearCase, this isn't so straightforward.
You need to list the last version of int_2, describing them in order to look for a merge hyperlink.
See "[How files and directories are merged](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm)"

[image: merge]

Here you would see, going back from the most recent to the oldest version of `test`, that the last merge from `main` was on version 3.
Describing that version would return:

```
cleartool describe util.h@@/main/3version "util.h@@/main/3"
.
.
.
Hyperlinks:
Merge@278@/vob_3 /vob_3/src/util.h@@/main/rel2_bugfix/1
-> /vob_3/src/util.h@@/main/3
```

You can also try:

```
cleartool describe -l util.h@@/main/3version
```

Comment: @user2210807 ok, I have edited the answer to cover base ClearCase.

Comment: Thank you VonC for the quick reply. For a particular file that is fine. But here if i have say 100 files with int_2 branch. And 50 files were merged in 1st merge from int_1, then say 30 files were merged in 2nd attempt and 10 in 3rd merge and rest 10 in fourth merge. So i have complete list of files having this branch int_2, but checking on each file is a bit difficult. i need to know here the fourth merge info which just have 10 files. And the date time when this merge was done.

Comment: @user2210807 I understand: you need to script the lookup process for each version of `int_2`, in order to collect the date of each most recent hyperlink, building back the 4 sets of merges. That is why UCM is much more convenient, adding "activities" in order to record precisely those successive merges.

Comment: @user2210807 but the short answer is: I don't know of a native `cleartool` command that would do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, your question has no answer because ClearCase doesn't have changesets or any feature that would represent a single "merge".  All you can do is search for merges that occurred between singular file-versions, and see what time each was performed.  If they were on the same day, or very close to each other in time, they probably represent one "merge".

For a motivating example to start with look at the manual via "cleartool man find", which lists some examples of using the merge(from-branch, to-branch) clause.

To get the versions int_1 that were merged to int_2, try:

```
ct find . -type f -branch 'brtype(int_1)' -version 'merge(/main/int_1,/main/int_2) && hltype(Merge,->)'
```

To see the target versions, add some additional processing, e.g.:

```
ct find . -type f -branch 'brtype(int_1)' -version 'merge(/main/int_1,/main/int_2) && hltype(Merge,->)' -exec 'echo -n "$CLEARCASE_XPN " && cleartool desc -short -ahlink Merge $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

To find out what time the merge occurred, you'll need to do some post-processing of the target version (e.g. cleartool desc -fmt '%Nd' ) to get the timestamp.